# How to properly write the values of an array into a JSON file using writeFile in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, json, automated-tests, cypress, writefile

I wanted to write the values of an array into a JSON file by using [writeFile](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/writefile#JSON) .

```
console.log(category);

cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/actionsName.json', category);
```

I've outputted the values of the ***category*** array. See below

[image: Value of the array]

My expected contents of the file would be something like this

[image]

However, upon writing the contents of the JSON file using [writeFile](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/writefile#JSON), it only prints the top level array, not including its contents.
[image: Contents of the file]

I'm not sure what I'm missing, I would really appreciate if someone can take a look. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**
As per request, below is the code used to populate the category array. Let me know if anything needs to be updated/optimized.

```
getActionName(){
    let category = new Array();
    let actions = new Array();

    //Get all action name and store to json
    cy.get('.linkbox').each(($category) => {

        //Get category name
        const text = $category.find('.heading').text();
        cy.log("Category: " + text);
        category.push(text);

        //Get each action name and push to the related category
        cy.wrap($category).find('ul li h2').each(($action) => {
            const text = $action.text();
            cy.log("Action: " + text);

            actions.push(text);
        }).then(() => {
            category[text] = actions;
            actions = [];
        })

    }).then(() =>{
        console.log(category);

        //!Only writes the top level array
        cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/actionsName.json', category);
    }) 
}
```

Comment: can you add the entire code ?

Comment: @AlapanDas Please see updates. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard to tell for sure from the screenshot, but I think the array has non-standard properties attached (an Array is an object).

Try converting,

```js
const keys = ['Alert', 'Dynamic Elements', 'Frames and Windows', etc]
const output = keys.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc[item] = category[item]
  return acc
}, {})
cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/actionsName.json', output)
```

Just looked at your posted code - the problem is as expected, you're attaching the lists to the array as properties. The above should work, or you can clean up the way you gather the lists.

```js
getActionName(){
    //let category = new Array();  // change this to an object
    let category = {};
    let actions = new Array();

    //Get all action name and store to json
    cy.get('.linkbox').each(($category) => {

        //Get category name
        const text = $category.find('.heading').text();
        cy.log("Category: " + text);
        //category.push(text);    // don't need this

        //Get each action name and push to the related category
        cy.wrap($category).find('ul li h2').each(($action) => {
            const text = $action.text();
            cy.log("Action: " + text);

            actions.push(text);
        }).then(() => {
            category[text] = actions;
            actions = [];
        })

    }).then(() =>{
        console.log(category);

        //!Only writes the top level array
        cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/actionsName.json', category);
    }) 
}
```

Comment: Yes, I missed that one. category variable should be an object. This works! Thank you